# Including Magento's "prototype/windows/themes/magento.css" Across Versions

Tags: css, magento, magento-layout-xml

I've got an Magento admin console extension that enables a model window across the entire Magento admin console.  In Magento 1.7, I can include the factory default CSS file with the following

```
$layout->getBlock('head')->addCss('lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css');
```

However, in Magento 1.6, this file isn't in the skin folder, it's in the 'js_css' folder, and I need to use this

```
$layout->getBlock('head')->addItem('js_css', 'prototype/windows/themes/magento.css')
```

Is there an elegant, straight forward way for me to ensure this file is properly included across all versions of Magento **without** resorting to version sniffing and **without** resorting to making my own copy of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I went this this for the time being — leaving the question open in the hopes something better comes along.

```
        //would fail if Magento lives in a sub-folder named base
        $skin_url = $design->getSkinUrl('lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css');
        $parts = explode('/',$skin_url);
        if(in_array('base', $parts))
        {
            $head->addItem('js_css', 'prototype/windows/themes/magento.css');
        }
        else
        {
            $head->addCss('lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css');    
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this suggestion is any better but you could check *where* the file exist and let that determine which method to call.

Comment: Yeah, maybe just store file_get_contents($file) in a variable and check if it's empty or not?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the safest way would be to distribute your own version of the file with your package.

- You will have absolute certainty of where the file resides after package installation
- No unnecessary FS hits
- No dependency on the version provided by Magento (of course this can backfire, as always)

Comment: What happens when my file interferes with the magento file on a magento where Magento code uses it?

Comment: Wow! You said "magento" three times in the same sentence. Time to take a break? Your question is exactly what I meant by backfiring. Is the same logic behind not overwriting core classes in local. I wouldn't use my own proposed solution in any circumstances, and I like your proposal better. But, if avoiding version sniffing (or version-dependent file structure checks) is a must, then I cannot see another solution